# Encountering error 08001 when attempting to connect to database

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

When I attempt to connect to an instance of a PostgreSQL database I've created as per the AWS "Create and Connect to a PostgreSQL Database with Amazon RDS" tutorial located here (https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/create-connect-postgresql-db/), I receive an error that reads:

> [08001] The connection attempt failed.
> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out.

The database is set to allow incoming and outgoing traffic on all ports and from all IP addresses. I am completely at a loss as to how to get this working and have reached out to AWS Support for their input, but, as yet, all I've done is follow the directions prescribed by the AWS tutorial--to no avail.

Does anyone know what might be the issue?

Edit: I should mention that all of my, host URL, port number, database name, etc. have been entered correctly into DataGrip, so none of the above are the issue.

Comment: Connection timeout is almost always a network connectivity issue. Are you trying to connect from within the VPC that the RDS instance is in, or from outside? Have you opened the security group appropriately?

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I'm attempting to connect to the database from my personal machine. I did check the security group, and there appear to be no restraints on incoming and outgoing traffic.

Comment: Is the RDS server configured to be Publicly Accessible?

Comment: It sure is, yes.

Comment: Does the subnet the RDS instance is in have a route to/from the internet?

Comment: I can't really tell, to be honest. I"m guessing that would look something like "0.0.0.0/16."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All right--I've figured it out.

First off, @Mark B was right--the issue was that I hadn't yet made the database itself publicly accessible via the VPC security group of which it was a member. To do this, from the database detail screen in AWS, I:

1. clicked (what for me was the one and only) link beneath the "VPC security groups" of the database's dashboard, which directed me to the EC2 Security Groups screen
2. clicked the security group link related to my database, which directed me to that group's detail page
3. clicked the "Edit inbound rules" button which directed me to the "Edit inbound rules" screen
4. clicked the "Add rule" button, which caused a table row containing the following columns: "Type", "Protocol," "Port Range," "Source," "Description - optional"
5. selected "PostgreSQL" for the "Type" column, which caused the values of "TCP" and "5432" to populate the "Protocol" and "Port range" columns respectively, entered my machine's IP address ("123.456.789.012/32"--no quotes and no parentheses), and left "Description - optional" blank, because, well, it's optional.

Finally, I guess I'd forgotten to explicitly name the database, and so my attempts to enter what for me was ostensibly the database's name (that is, "database-1") resulted in a connection error indicating that "database-1" does not exist. So, for the sake of ease and simply verifying my database connection, I entered "postgres" as the database name in my database client (I'm presently using DataGrip), because "postgres" is the de facto name of a postgreSQL database.

And that should work. I'm sure this is all no-brainer stuff to those more experienced with AWS, but it's new to me and presumably to many others.

Thanks again, @Mark B, for sending me down the right path.